# Using swift 3 migrator more than once

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

My current code is in swift 2.2 and i want to migrate it to swift 3.0 so what is the best way to migrate the code? Should i use migrator or should i use manually.

Regarding migrator i tried it once and there very bunch of errors still after migration was completed and then i need to manually fix the issues. So am i doing it correct?

I tried to use migrator tool more than once it still did fix some of the issues and then again i build it has still errors. Every time i build the code new issues comes up.
So what is the correct way to solve or migrate the code to swift 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the migrator once. You have to fix the remaining issues yourself. Running the same migration multiple times will not help you.

After the migration you will find errors. After fixing those errors new ones will show up. You have to continue fixing them all manually.

I had around 100 compile errors in total, tracked back to 13 compile time issues. Until now I have found 2 fatal runtime issues. One runtime issue only manifests itself on iOS 10.

I have written a [detailed blog post](http://peterfennema.nl/migration-of-an-ios-app-to-xcode8-swift3/) about my own app migration.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you shall go through this migration guide first: https://swift.org/migration-guide/

Normally we use Conversion Wizard provides by Apple first, and we fix the remaining issues manually.

It's tedious but no perfect solutions yet...